Best way to maintain a PrimeNG custom theme
Recently I have added an ngPrime custom theme based on the instructions from their website https://primeng.org/theming. In short I downloaded the primeng-sass-theme from their github repo and started editing the files in myTheme folder (where you are supposed to add all your custom styles). In that folder there is an extension file scss partial where you can add your overrides. But you also have access to a variable folder, which contains the file of every components and their respective scss variables (e.g button.scss, overlay.scss etc). My question is, what would be the most maintainable approach when updating ngPrime library?

Should I apply only the styles I want for the components in the override files

// _extension.scss
.p-inputtext {
    padding: 10px;
 }


Directly set the values in the scss variables for the component in the variable folder

// variable/_form.scss
    $inputPadding: 10px;

Or there is a better alternative solution
